# Probability of something happening exactly x times given y tries

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm working on my stats homework, and I completely forgot how to do this. Also, we were only taught how to do it on a calculator (TI84) and I want to know how to do it without one.
The problem is pretty much "what is the problem of it happening exactly twice given we try it ten times?" and the probability of it happening each time is .17.

Comment: Watch this video. It tells you how to compute the binomial coefficient $n \choose k$ with TI84: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qygmM6XHapk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of it in terms of a string, F=failure, and S=success.

Your string might look like SSFFFFFFFF or any other re-ordering of those terms (so long as you have 2 successes and 8 failures).  The probability of any specific string occurring is $p^{2}(1-p)^{8}$ where $p$ is the probability of success (in this case $p=.17$).  Now, how many strings can you have?  There are 10 entries and you have to choose 2 to make your successes (the rest are failures).  So there are $\binom{10}{2}$ (or nCr(10,2) on the calculator) such strings.  The final probability is: $\binom{10}{2}(.17)^{2}(.83)^{8}$.

To expand: suppose you want to know the probability of exactly $x$ successes given $y$ tries, with probability $p$ of success.  Then the probability is $\binom{y}{x}p^{x}(1-p)^{y-x}$.