# Probability of something happening *at least* X times given Y tries?

Tags: probability

I'm piggybacking my question off of this question:

[Probability of something happening exactly x times given y tries](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260572/probability-of-something-happening-exactly-x-times-given-y-tries)

But I'm curious to know how to calculate the chance of something happening at least X amount of times given Y tries.

Let's say I need at least 2 successes over 4 tries, and I have a 25% chance of success. I understand my chance is:

$\binom{4}{2}(.25)^{2}(.75)^{2}$  +  $\binom{4}{3}(.25)^{3}·0.75$  +  $\binom{4}{4}(.25)^{4}$

Or ~26.2%

Is there a way to calculate this, in a much easier way that doesn't involve manually adding each calculation? I'm considering this type of calculation with the following parameters:

- At least 10 successes
- 220 tries
- 0.3% chance of success

I'd prefer to avoid calculating the below equation 210 times and adding them together.

> $\binom{y}{x}p^{x}(1-p)^{y-x}$

Comment: The you have to use an approximation.  The normal and Poisson distributions are often used for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the complement:
$$1-\sum_{k=0}^9 \binom{220}{k} p^k (1-p)^{220-k}$$

Comment: Oh that's true. I guess if my k is small, I could definitely use the "one minus" of everything below it. That's a lot more manageable, thanks!